# Mockito keep returning null even after stub

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have some structure like this

```
...
SomeDao dao = getDAO(AttributeDAO.class);
CustomType type =dao.findByKey(typeOne, typeTwo, typeThree.toString());
if(type == null) {
    System.out.print("null returned");
} else {
    System.out.print("do something");
}
...
```

My test cases

```
...
        MainClass mc = Mockito.spy(new MainClass());
        CustomType type = new CustomType();
        SomeDao dao = Mockito.mock(AttributeDAO.class);
        type.setValueOne(1);
        type.setValueTwo(1);
        type.setValueThree("Y");
        Mockito.doReturn(type).when(dao).findByKey(1,2,"Y");

        mc.callThisDaoFunction();
...
```

But whenever I tried to return the type with eclemma coverage tool it keep saying that `type == null` how do I my test case or set up for the type to return a non null value?

Comment: I would think you need to override the behavior of that getDAO() method to return your mock DAO...otherwise, the mock probably is not called and it seems likely that your actual SUT may not have been configured adequately for the test (i.e., type is actually null). I tend to use JMockit, and that will do byte code replacement such that just annotating your mock DAO will replace the DAO in your SUT without additional effort on your part.

Comment: So, possibly, since you have a spy..after creating your CustomType.. Mockito.doReturn(type).when(mc).getDAO(anyObject());

Comment: I see, reading @Alexander's response, that I meant Mockito.doReturn(dao) rather than Mockito.doReturn(type) above. That would seem to connect the dots..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject your *dao* mock to your *MainClass*. Otherwise it will still try to retrieve the real *dao* when calling *getDao(AttributeDAO.class)*.

- If there is a method *setDao* it would be just calling it with your mock.
- Otherwise return *dao* when *mc* is invoked with the parameter *AttributeDAO.class*.

Comment: Really? Mockito.doReturn(dao).when(mc).getDao(AttributeDAO.class);